# Channel not showing all items?

Tags: channels, feed

We have a channel on the following page that shows 'Issues' of our magazine: http://ambitmagazine.co.uk/issues

We have issues going all the way back to issue 1, but the channel page currently only shows issues back as far as issue 32:
http://ambitmagazine.co.uk/issues/32 (displaying in the channel feed)
http://ambitmagazine.co.uk/issues/31 (not displaying but the URL returns the issue information, and no other settings are different in the backend).

Does anyone know why this page might not be showing everything? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Set a limit of nulll on your entry query which means no limit. If you do not specify a limit, you will only see 100 entries.

```
.limit(null)
```

Comment: ^ True for Craft 2 - Craft 3 will grab them all by default.